# Calling a function of a button from another button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a complicated case here, but below is an example just to make it simple.
I have two buttons, each with their own onClick function. I want to call the onClick function of button A when I click on button B.

```
<input id="buttonA" type="button" value="BUTTON A" onMouseUp="sayHiA()"></input>
<input id="buttonB" type="button" value="BUTTON B" onClick="sayHiB()"></input>
```

Note that the event can be onClick() or onMouseUp()

p.s. I have to do it using only javascript. (NO jQuery). Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<input type="button" onclick="fnc()"/>
<input type="button" id="message" onclick="alert('ok')" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function fnc()
{

document.getElementById("message").click();
}
</script>
```

are you looking for this?

Comment: Thanks, but what if it was onMouseUp? is there a way to detect what is the event type in the button?

Answer (score 3):

```
<html>
<head>//I guess something like setTimeout(function,timeInMilliseconds)
    <script language = "javascript">
    function sayHiA(){
            var v  = document.getElementById('buttonB').getAttribute("onClick");
        setTimeout(v,0);
    }
    function sayHiB(){

        document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = 'wrote';

    }
</script>

</head>
<body>

<input id="buttonA" type="button" value="BUTTON A" onMouseUp="sayHiA()"></input>
<input id="buttonB" type="button" value="BUTTON B" onClick="sayHiB()"></input>

<p id = "para">
Write Here
</p>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: When buttonB is clicked it will change para from "write here" to "wrote". Similarly buttonA will do the same but grab the attribute of onClick from buttonB and set it as the call back function for the timeout. The timeout time is 0 so it will be run right away calling sayHiB() from sayHiA().

Comment: eval can be uses instead of setTimeout to run any code in the on click attribute. eval(v);

Answer (score 1):

```
function sayHiB() {
    sayHiA();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried this with an external js ? This is quite the most basic thing you can do in javascript.

I made you a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pjDVP/4/

The html :

```
<input id='bta' type='button' value='button a'></input>
<input id='btb' type='button' value='button b'></input>​
```

The js (with jquery laoded) :

```
$(function(){
    $('#bta').click(function(){aORbClick();});
    $('#btb').click(function(){aORbClick();});
})

function aORbClick(){alert('I clicked a or b');}
```

Answer (score 0):

just call function `sayHiA` from `sayHiB` or call it after.

Call from sayHiB

```
function sayHiB()
{
   sayHiA();
}
```

or after

```
<input id="buttonB" type="button" value="BUTTON B" onClick="sayHiB(); sayHiA();"></input>
```

or easier way is to use jQuery, so you can do this

```
function sayHiB(){
   if($('#id-of-a').attr('onclick'))
       $('#id-of-a').click();
   else if ($('#id-of-a').attr('onmouseup'))
       $('#id-of-a').mouseUp();

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to do it with pure Javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
function sayHiB(){
    $('#buttonA').click();
}
```

Raw JS:

```
function sayHiB(){
    var buttonA = document.getElementById('buttonA');
    buttonA.onclick.apply(buttonA); // in onclick function you can get buttonA as 'this'
}
```

Comment: I don't see the question tagged with jQuery.

Comment: I was trying to do it only with Javascript

Comment: but what if it was onMouseUp? is there a way to detect what is the event type in the button?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably make a generic function that switches on the button's name/id to figure out what to do - this would also make your code work independent of the event attribute used to call the function.

HTML:

```
<input id="buttonA" type="button" value="BUTTON A" onMouseUp="myFunc(this)"></input>
<input id="buttonB" type="button" value="BUTTON B" onClick="myFunc(this)"></input>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunc(elem){
    switch(elem.id){
        case 'buttonA':
            sayHiA();
            break;
        case 'buttonB':
            sayHiB();
            sayHiA();
            break;
    }
}
```

This would also help with any DOM manipulation you might need as the button which was clicked is passed to the generic function `myFunc`, allowing you to quickly access other attributes or nearby elements.